# How to send a compressed archive that contains executables so that Google's attachment filter won't reject it

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I have a directory that I want to compress to send it by e-mail, I've tried this:

```
tar -cvf filename.tar.gz directory_to_compress/
```

But when I try to send it by e-mail, Google says:

```
filename.tar.gz contains an executable file. For security reasons, Gmail does not allow you to send this type of file.
```

How to compress a directory into a `tar.gz` file from command line?

Comment: Isn't the question about bypassing Google's protection ?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
tar -cvzf filename.tar.gz directory_to_compress/
```

Most `tar` commands have a `z` option to create a `gzip`ed version.

Though seems to me the question is how to circumvent Google. I'm not sure if renaming your output file would fool Google, but you could try. I.e.,

```
tar -cvzf filename.bla directory_to_compress/
```

and then send the `filename.bla` - contents will would be a zipped tar, so at the other end it could be retrieved as usual.

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 8):

To bypass google's check, which is what you really want, simply remove the extensions from the file when you send it, and add them back after you download it.
For example:

- tar czvf file.tar.gz directory
- mv file.tar.gz filetargz
- [send filetargz via gmail]
- [download filetargz]
- [rename filetargz to file.tar.gz and open]

Comment: Thanks you, the @Levon answer works, but it's great know about another solutions

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Another easy way to circumvent google's check is to use another compression algorithm with tar, like bz2:

```
tar -cvjf my.tar.bz2 dir/
```

Note that 'j' (for bz2 compression) is used above instead of 'z' (gzip compression).

Comment: Doesn't work any more

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tar -czf my.tar.gz dir/
```

But are you sure you are not compressing some .exe file or something? Maybe the problem is not with te compression, but with the files you are compressing?